# Is there a command in the VSCode API that can check if a language server is available for a given language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I am currently writing a *VScode* extension where i use functionalities provided by installed language server. I need to know **if there is any way to check if a language server for a given language is installed**.
For example, something like the following commands that could check if a language server for Java is installed, or if I can safely use the find all references for Java

`vscode.executeCommand("language-server.is-installed", "java")`
`vscode.executeCommand("language-server.can-find-references", "java")`

I look into the API's documentations but i could not find any indication regarding my need.
Thank's in advance for the help !

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps it's a good idea to file a bug for VSCode for that.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112143) on vscode's repo; But now answer since the 15th of december